# Importing ArcPy in 64bit Python?

Tags: arcpy, installation, 64bit, spyder

I have to use 64bit python. So, I install Background Processing 64bit and change the interpreter of Spyder into python 64bit in ArcGISx6410.3.
[image: import failure]

but I can import successfully in ArcMap' python window
[image: arcmap window]

my OS is window7 64 bit
and ArcGIS is 10.3.0

Comment: It sounds like you've got crossed paths, I can see it's importing from 32bit python in 64bit environment. You need to pre-set your path system variables to the 64bit libs. In the ArcMap window it's 32bit python.. is there a reason why you want 64bit? I don't see it worth the effort, stick with 32bit methinks, it works just fine.

Comment: Hello, Miles. A [remote sensing Plug-in](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/l2a-process-help-fails-and-openjp2-cannot-be-loaded-still-in-2-2-1/2992) must using 64bit python. I thought arcpy library would be adapted to 64bit python after installing background proceesing so I imported it directly. I have referred some blogs and it seems a quite complicated for novice like me.

Comment: It can be Very complex trying to maintain two pythons on the same computer, I would recommend starting your editor with a batch file that overwrites %path% with the 64bit environment, that should be all you need to get this working - if that doesn't help you might need to post on Stack Overflow as this is more a python problem than ArcGis, the great people there have a much more in-depth understanding of python itself than many who only use it for arcpy.

Comment: To rule out Spyder, try opening a `cmd` prompt to `c:\python27\ArcGISx6410.3` and start python, then input `import arcpy`

Comment: @Midavalo, the true problem is I cannot import arcpy in this python interpreter although I reinstall several times sadly.

Comment: Do you have anything in your environment path for python?  Seems odd to me - I have nothing in my path and have no trouble with either 32bit or 64bit arcpy, which is why I wondered whether it's Spyder rather than arcpy (I've never used Spyder so couldn't say why or why not)